# Junit testing error, null pointer in mock method

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am trying to testing my controller. My controller call a service method and this service only do a simple web service call. I am trying to mock my service for do a testing over my controller but in testing execution, my service throw an error becouse my Client class inside my service is null.

My Controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "This endpoint sends the customer's registration data and returns information about the properties of the offer.", response = Oferta.class)
    @PostMapping(path="/concurrentoffers/offer")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Oferta>> postOfertaAsync(@Valid @RequestBody OfertaRequest inDTO) 
            throws IOException, SOAPException, CompletionException,  WebServiceBadResponseException{
        
        logger.info("Start REST postOferta");
        
        CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Oferta>> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
            try {
                Oferta oferta = ofertasService.identificacionOferta(inDTO).get();
                return ResponseEntity.ok(oferta);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw  new CompletionException(e);
            }
        });
```

My Service not all we don't need all code:

```
package es.****.ofertasconcurrenteswow.services;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import es.******.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.ClientCrm;
import es.*******.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.dtos.OfertaCrm;
import es.*******.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.dtos.OfertaRequestCRM;
import es.********.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.dtos.PropuestaCompraCrm;
import es.********.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.dtos.RespuestaPropuestaCrm;
import es.*******.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.daos.PropuestaCompraRepository;
import es.*******.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.daos.entities.PropuestaCompraEntity;
import es.**********.ofertasconcurrenteswow.mapper.EntityMapper;
import es.**********.ofertasconcurrenteswow.mapper.OfertasMapper;
import es.************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.Oferta;
import es.***********.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.OfertaRequest;
import es.*************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.PropuestaCompra;
import es.***************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.RespuestaPropuesta;
import es.***************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.services.email.EmailService;
import es.*******************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.services.exceptions.WebServiceBadResponseException;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Service @NoArgsConstructor
public class OfertasConcurrentesService {
    
    private ClientCrm clientCrm;
    private EmailService emailService;
    private PropuestaCompraRepository propuestaCompraRepository;

    private OfertasMapper mapper = OfertasMapper.INSTANCE;
    private EntityMapper entityMapper = EntityMapper.INSTANCE;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OfertasConcurrentesService.class);

    public OfertasConcurrentesService(ClientCrm clientCrm, EmailService emailService,
            PropuestaCompraRepository propuestaCompraRepository) {
        super();
        this.clientCrm = clientCrm;
        this.emailService = emailService;
        this.propuestaCompraRepository = propuestaCompraRepository;
    }
    
    
    public CompletableFuture<Oferta> identificacionOferta(OfertaRequest inDTO) {

        logger.info("Start identificacionOferta");
        
        logger.debug("Mapeamos el dto de entrada rest a el dto de entrada del WSCrm");
        OfertaRequestCRM inDTOCrm = mapper.ofertaRequestDtoRestToOfertaRequestDtoCrm(inDTO);

        logger.debug("Preparamos llamda al Cliente WebService");
        CompletableFuture<OfertaCrm> completableFutureCRM = clientCrm.llamadaWebServiceOfertasAsync(inDTOCrm)
                .thenApply(ofertaCrm -> {
                    // TODO: es el campo codigo?
                    if ("2".equals(ofertaCrm.getCodigo())) {
                        throw new CompletionException(new WebServiceBadResponseException(ofertaCrm.getMensaje()));
                    }
                    return ofertaCrm;
                });
```

My testing controller class:

```
package es.servihabitat.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import es.************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.ClientCrm;
import es.***************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.ClientCrmDummyImpl;
import es.****************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.Inmueble;
import es.***************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.Oferta;
import es.****************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.rest.dtos.OfertaRequest;
import es.**********************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.services.OfertasConcurrentesService;
import es.*******************.ofertasconcurrenteswow.services.exceptions.WebServiceBadResponseException;
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class OfertaConcurrenteControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private ClientCrm clientCrm;/* = new ClientCrmDummyImpl();*/
    
    @Mock
    OfertasConcurrentesService ofertasService ;
    @InjectMocks
    OfertaConcurrenteController ofertasController;
    @Autowired
    OfertaRequest ofertaRequest;
    @BeforeAll
     void init() {
        clientCrm=new ClientCrmDummyImpl(); 
        ofertasService = new OfertasConcurrentesService();
        ofertasController = new OfertaConcurrenteController();
        
    }
    @Test
    void testPostOfertaAsync() throws CompletionException, IOException, SOAPException, WebServiceBadResponseException {
        List<Inmueble> listaInmuebles = new ArrayList<Inmueble>();
        listaInmuebles.add(new Inmueble("a","b","c","s","r","t","u"));
        Oferta oferta = new Oferta((long)266500000,LocalDateTime.of(2017, 2, 13, 15, 56),listaInmuebles);
        CompletableFuture<Oferta> futuro = new CompletableFuture<Oferta>();
        futuro.complete(oferta);
        
        ofertaRequest = new OfertaRequest("00457","087945","5642564z","4564","mail@mail.mail");
        when(ofertasService.identificacionOferta(ofertaRequest)).thenReturn(futuro);
        
        //when(ofertasService.identificacionOferta(any(OfertaRequest.class))).thenReturn();
        
        assert ofertasController.postOfertaAsync(ofertaRequest) !=null ;
    }

    @Test
    void testPropuestaCompra() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

And the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "es.********.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.ClientCrm.llamadaWebServiceOfertasAsync(es.****.ofertasconcurrenteswow.data.apis.crm.dtos.OfertaRequestCRM)" because "this.clientCrm" is null
```

Comment: Can you replace '@BeforeAll' with '@BeforeEach' ? @AlejandroMartin

Comment: Yes, Now I remove my service constructor but now my "ofertasService" is null, I can't instance my ofertasService in my test class with no constructor?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using JUnit 5 and mocking some classes you need to tell Spring that you are using mockito and its annotations like `@Mock`. You have 3 options to do it.

1 - use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` when defining your test class.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class OfertaConcurrenteControllerTest {
  @Mock private ClientCrm clientCrm;
···
```

I prefer this because `@ExtendWith` is compatible with other extensions.

2 - use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` to start mockito for your test class

```
class OfertaConcurrenteControllerTest {
  @Mock private ClientCrm clientCrm;
  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
...
```

This is still declarative because you use the `@Mock` but you miss the junit5 framework validation.

3 - create the mock object yourself `Mockito.mock(ClientCrm.class)`.

```
class OfertaConcurrenteControllerTest {
  private ClientCrm clientCrm;
  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    Mockito.mock(ClientCrm.class)
  }
...
```

This is more verbose but you will have more control of what your mock objects are doing.